# Create a new column based on groupby a column value and count of another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Birds': ['Falcon','Falcon','Parrot','Peacock','Peacock'],
                   'Name': ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'C']})
```

I need to create a new column,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Birds': ['Falcon','Falcon','Parrot','Peacock','Peacock'],
                   'Name': ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'C']
                   'Count':['1','1','0','0','0'] })
```

Falcon has two names, so each records given 1, parrot and peacock has only one name which is B for parrot and C for peacock, so new column has 0.

I tried using groupby

```
df.groupby(['Birds','Name']).size()
```

this returns

```
Birds    Name
Falcon   A        1
         D        1
Parrot   B        1
Peacock  C        2
dtype: int64
```

Not sure how to convert this

Another way, subset and drop duplicates

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Birds', 'Name'], keep='first')
df2['Birds'].value_counts()
```

this returns

```
Falcon     2
Peacock    1
Parrot     1
Name: Birds, dtype: int64
```

Not sure how to use this to create new column in original as 1 and 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` combined with `nunique`:

```py
df["count"] =  df.groupby("Birds")["Name"].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() - 1)
```

**Without `lambda` - Option 1**

```py
df["count"] =  df.groupby("Birds")["Name"].transform("nunique") - pd.Series([1] * df.shape[0])
```

**Without `lambda` - Option 2**

```py
df["count"] =  df.groupby("Birds")["Name"].transform("nunique")
df["count"] =  df["count"] -1
```

Comment: is it possible to do without using lambda expression, Thanks

Comment: Included two alternatives without the use of lambdas (:

Comment: great and Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby(['Birds'])['Name'].transform('nunique') - 1` is a little nicer imo

Comment: Good point @Datanovice! Forgot (partially) about the `broadcasting` feature in `pandas`